# Вывод данных из json в discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу вывести все товары в Embed через discord py по api.

Сам json ответ от api:

```
    {
"response":{
    "categories":[
        {
            "id":0,
            "name":"Без категории",
            "items":[
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"Чай",
                    "cost":30,
                    "description":"описание 1",
                    "image":"https://imgur.com/1"
                },
                {
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"Кофе",
                    "cost":50,
                    "description":"Описание 2",
                    "image":"https://imgur.com/2"
                },
                    "fields":[
                        {
                            "id":"subfield",
                            "placeholder":"Пожелания к чаю",
                            "flags":"dwos"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Как я могу вывести все товары в embed?
При попытке вывести определённый товар сталкиваюсь с такой вот ошибкой:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 167, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Codding\! DISCORD BOTS\AlbiApi\bot.py", line 29, in allitems
    tovar = data['items'][0]['name']
KeyError: 'items'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 994, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 894, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 176, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'items'
```

Мой код:

```
@bot.command()
async def allitems(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("Получаю все товары в донате...")
    url = 'https://api.trademc.org/shop.getItems?shop=177187&v=3'
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    data = response.json()
    tovar = data['items'][0]['name']
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="", description=f"**{tovar}**", color = 0x2f3136))
```

Обновлено:

Пример ответа api с офф.документации:

```
{
    "response":{
        "categories":[
            {
                "id":0,
                "name":"Без категории",
                "items":[
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Демо-товар ✨",
                        "cost":1,
                        "description":"Это демо-товар. Попробуйте провести пробную транзакцию - это займет не более 5 минут. Все очень просто!",
                        "image":"https://i.trademc.org/items/333ea76ff35c974003bb1bfe52d76090.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"Кофе",
                        "cost":50,
                        "description":"Понравился сервис? Угостите программистов кофе ",
                        "image":"https://i.trademc.org/items/f3741b92b351323338da9b02e38dec2f.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":3,
                        "name":"VIP ",
                        "cost":100,
                        "description":"Дает привилегию VIP на несуществующем сервере. В описании можно использовать Emoji , а сам товар может содержать дополнительные поля",
                        "image":"https://i.trademc.org/items/b5405b3f88a17ccf4c468f7eb1ec7ed5.jpg",
                        "fields":[
                            {
                                "id":"subfield",
                                "placeholder":"Дополнительное поле товара VIP ",
                                "flags":"dwos"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `data['categories']['items'][0]['name']` ну они же в категориях находятся.

Comment: Да, я так уже пытался.
Получал такую ошибку:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'categories'

Comment: а да , там еще `['response']` `data['response']['categories']['items'][0]['name']`

Comment: Черт. И снова ошибка, только уже такого содержания:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: вы уверены что вставили правильно пример `json` который приходит в ответ?

Comment: обновил, добавил пример ответа с офф.документации api. Там точно всё верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

там была ошибка из-за копипаста
в общем вот, все работает. Ну только в зависимости от количество категорий и товара нужны будут циклы

```
json_1={
    "response":{
        "categories":[
            {
                "id":0,
                "name":"Без категории",
                "items":[
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Демо-товар ✨",
                        "cost":1,
                        "description":"Это демо-товар. Попробуйте провести пробную транзакцию - это займет не более 5 минут. Все очень просто!",
                        "image":"https://i.trademc.org/items/333ea76ff35c974003bb1bfe52d76090.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"Кофе",
                        "cost":50,
                        "description":"Понравился сервис? Угостите программистов кофе ",
                        "image":"https://i.trademc.org/items/f3741b92b351323338da9b02e38dec2f.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":3,
                        "name":"VIP ",
                        "cost":100,
                        "description":"Дает привилегию VIP на несуществующем сервере. В описании можно использовать Emoji , а сам товар может содержать дополнительные поля",
                        "image":"https://i.trademc.org/items/b5405b3f88a17ccf4c468f7eb1ec7ed5.jpg",
                        "fields":[
                            {
                                "id":"subfield",
                                "placeholder":"Дополнительное поле товара VIP ",
                                "flags":"dwos"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
print(json_1['response']['categories'][0]['items'][0]['name'])
```